# How to set positioning properly in PDF document? (Typeset.sh for laravel)

Tags: css, laravel, typeset

Using typset.sh, I am able to generate PDF documents through blade. I am trying to set a fixed size بخق all images in the document plus organize them in a grid.

In this PDF, there are 10 images, 8 can be fit in 1 page, so the last two are moved to the second page. Correct however, the 2 before are rendering at the very end ignoring the margin rule i set for `@page` which is a bug I am trying to fix, please see screenshot:

[image]
[image: 2]

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="images">
            @foreach ($record->incident_images as $image)
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $image) }}" />
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </section>
```

Typset CSS code to setup the document:

```
@page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 10mm;
            /* bleed: 13mm; */

            @bottom-center {
                content: 'Page 'counter(page) ' of 'counter(pages);
            }
        }
```

This is the images css:

```
section#images {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            gap: 2mm;
            margin-top: 0; /* Adjust the top margin as needed */
            margin-bottom: 0; /* Adjust the bottom margin as needed */
        }

        .image {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            break-inside: avoid; /* Ensure that each container stays together on a single page */
        }

        .image>img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200vh; /* Set the image height to 50% of the viewport height */
            object-fit: cover;
        }
```

According to the documentation, I tried to using page breaks but the issue still isn't fixed:

> **Page break control** 
> `break-before` and `break-after`: These properties can
> be used to specify where a page break should or should never occur
> before or after an element. 
> `break-inside`: This property can be used to
> prevent a page break from occurring within an element. 
> `orphans` and `widows`: These properties can be used to specify the minimum number of
> lines that must appear at the top or bottom of a page before a page
> break is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `img` element outgrows the image container `div.image` element (you can see the border). That could mean that the layout engine does not cut it off as the `div.image` element does actually fit.

Why the height of 200vh ?

Might be an issue with the layout engine. You create a reproducible sample HTML and report it.